# Taxonomy - Display terms for post

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I've created the custom shortcode to display terms of a custom taxonomy.

```
// First we create a function
function list_terms_forme_juridique_taxonomy( $atts ) {

// Inside the function we extract custom taxonomy parameter of our 
shortcode

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
'custom_taxonomy' => 'forme_juridique',
 ), 
                $atts ) );

// arguments for function wp_list_categories
$args = array( 
taxonomy => $custom_taxonomy,
title_li => ''
);

// We wrap it in unordered list 
echo '<ul>'; 
echo wp_list_categories($args);
echo '</ul>';
}

// Add a shortcode that executes our function
add_shortcode( 'forme_juridique', 'list_terms_forme_juridique_taxonomy' 
);
```

It works well, but the issue is that ALL the terms are displayed. I'd like to display only the terms corresponding to the post itself.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) will work for you - it returns the terms of the custom taxonomy that are attached to the post (you must have the ID of the current post).